# Why does Method access seem faster than Field access?

Tags: java, optimization, benchmarking

I was doing some tests to find out what the speed differences are between using getters/setters and direct field access. I wrote a simple benchmark application like this:

```
public class FieldTest {

    private int value = 0;

    public void setValue(int value) {
        this.value = value;
    }

    public int getValue() {
        return this.value;
    }

    public static void doTest(int num) {
        FieldTest f = new FieldTest();

        // test direct field access
        long start1 = System.nanoTime();

        for (int i = 0; i < num; i++) {
            f.value = f.value + 1;
        }
        f.value = 0;

        long diff1 = System.nanoTime() - start1;

        // test method field access
        long start2 = System.nanoTime();

        for (int i = 0; i < num; i++) {
            f.setValue(f.getValue() + 1);
        }
        f.setValue(0);

        long diff2 = System.nanoTime() - start2;

        // print results
        System.out.printf("Field Access:  %d ns\n", diff1);
        System.out.printf("Method Access: %d ns\n", diff2);
        System.out.println();
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) throws InterruptedException {
        int num = 2147483647;

        // wait for the VM to warm up
        Thread.sleep(1000);

        for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
            doTest(num);
        }
    }

}
```

Whenever I run it, I get consistent results such as these: http://pastebin.com/hcAtjVCL

I was wondering if someone could explain to me why field access seems to be slower than getter/setter method access, and also why the last 8 iterations execute incredibly fast.

---

**Edit**: Having taken into account `assylias` and `Stephen C` comments, I have changed the code to http://pastebin.com/Vzb8hGdc where I got slightly different results: http://pastebin.com/wxiDdRix .

Comment: I think the compiler inlines the getters anyway. Have you checked the bytecode?

Comment: `/* wait for the VM to warm up */ Thread.sleep(1000);` - that's not how it works. The JVM does not warmup if it does nothing... Your micro benchmark has several flaws. In particular: (i) you don't really allow the JVM to warmup (ii) the two paths you want to test are in the same method, which might prevent some optimisations.

Comment: @jlordo - the inlining is done by the JIT compiler.  I won't be apparent in the bytecodes.

Comment: I have checked the bytecode (http://pastebin.com/Qqg4DbyN), and it would seem that the compiler doesn't inline it. However, as Stephen C says, it gets inlined by the JIT compiler.

Comment: And actually, looking at the times, it looks like the whole loop has been optimised away...

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The explanation is that your benchmark is broken.

The first iteration is done using the interpreter.

```
Field Access:  1528500478 ns
Method Access: 1521365905 ns
```

The second iteration is done by the interpreter to start with and then we flip to running JIT compiled code.

```
Field Access:  1550385619 ns
Method Access: 47761359 ns
```

The remaining iterations are all done using JIT compiled code.

```
Field Access:  68 ns
Method Access: 33 ns

etcetera
```

The reason they are *unbelievably* fast is that the JIT compiler has **optimized the loops away**.  It has detected that they were not contributing anything useful to the computation.  (It is not clear why the first number seems consistently faster than the second, but I doubt that the optimized code is measuring field versus method access in any meaningful way.)

---

Re the **UPDATED** code / results: it is obvious that the JIT compiler is still optimizing the loops away.

Comment: So @Stephen using accessors methods not only favor encapsulation, it also favor speed?? That's great to hear!!!

Comment: @Victor - I don't believe you can draw that conclusion.  Indeed, I don't believe you can draw **any** conclusion from this benchmarking.  It is simply flawed

Comment: Thanks Stephen! I see... i was starting to think that. So if you seek speed use direct access, if you a looking foward a more flexible design, use accessors methods? (Sorry for the offtopic question!)

Comment: I don't think you can draw that conclusion either.  My understanding is that a good JIT compiler will inline a simple getter or setter so that they perform the same as a direct field access / update.